# How do I print items out of a list horizontally in rows of specific length in Python?

Tags: python, list

I am very new to Python and have been given the following exercise.

Write a program that prints the whole chess board in the following way:

```
A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 A6 A7 A8
B1 B2 B3 B4 B5 B6 B7 B8
C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7 C8
D1 D2 D3 D4 D5 D6 D7 D8
E1 E2 E3 E4 E5 E6 E7 E8
F1 F2 F3 F4 F5 F6 F7 F8
G1 G2 G3 G4 G5 G6 G7 G8
H1 H2 H3 H4 H5 H6 H7 H8
```

So far, this is what I've done:

```
letter_fields=["A", "B", "C", "D","E","F", "G", "H"]
number_fields=["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"]

for letter in letter_fields:
    for number in number_fields:
        print (letter+number, end="")
```

So I have now printed everything horizontally, but not sure how to make it into specific rows. I have tried adding empty spaces in the print line, however, can't quite get it to align. This is meant to be done without anything too complicated as this is only the 4th lesson.. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Given what you may have already learned, you can use a space as the `end` argument for `print`, and print a new line after each inner loop finishes:

```
for letter in letter_fields:
    for number in number_fields:
        print (letter+number, end=" ")
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

[@blhsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61485367/how-do-i-print-items-out-of-a-list-horizontally-in-rows-of-specific-length-in-py/61485420#61485420) offers a good fix for your current code.

Another solution would be loop over every letter, build the horizontal row using a list comprehension, them print the joined coordinates on each line using [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
for letter in letter_fields:
    row = [letter + number for number in number_fields]
    print(" ".join(row))
```

**Output:**

```
A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 A6 A7 A8
B1 B2 B3 B4 B5 B6 B7 B8
C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7 C8
D1 D2 D3 D4 D5 D6 D7 D8
E1 E2 E3 E4 E5 E6 E7 E8
F1 F2 F3 F4 F5 F6 F7 F8
G1 G2 G3 G4 G5 G6 G7 G8
H1 H2 H3 H4 H5 H6 H7 H8
```